# How to make a responsive bar out of a dynamic values coming from the database

Tags: php, html, css, responsive

Good day! I'm having a problem doing a responsive navigation bar coming from HTML, PHP, and CSS only. (No DIVS/Navbar) As you can see below in the OUTPUT image. WHen I used a mobile phone or resize my browser into smaller one. It will output my values like in the OUTPUT image. What I want is to when I use mobile or just make my browser smaller. There will be a button containing all the values and hwen its clicked. it will breakdown all my values like this. This is an example of my desired output. Please see my desired output
[image]

Here's my CSS

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
 
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
 
/* This hides the dropdowns */
 
 
li ul { display: none; }
 
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000000;
}
 
ul li a:hover { background: #e4e3e3; }
 
/* Display the dropdown */
 
 
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
 
li:hover li { float: none; }
 
li:hover a { background: #f8f8f8; }
 
li:hover li a:hover { background: #e4e3e3; }
 
.main-navigation li ul li { 
color: black;
position: relative !important; 
z-index: 9999 !important;

  border-top: 0; }
 
/* Displays second level dropdowns to the right of the first level dropdown */
 
 
ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
 
/* Simple clearfix */

ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}
 
ul:after { clear: both; }
```

Here's my HTML, PHP Code:

```html
<?php 
function get_menu_tree($parentID) 
{
 global $con;
 $menu = "";
 $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM category where parentID='" .$parentID . "' ";
 $res=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
 {
           
           $menu .="<li><a href='base?page=post&categoryID=".$row['categoryID']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";  

     $menu .= "<ul>".get_menu_tree($row['categoryID'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively     
      $menu .= "</li>";
    }
    return $menu;  
} 
?>
```

Here's how I call the function from my HTML code:

```html
 
<div class="container">
  <ul class="main-navigation">

  <?php echo get_menu_tree(0); ?>

  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This my DATABASE structure
[image]

This is my OUTPUT out of the following codes
[image]

Comment: Please provide only *necessary* info in your question, I personally do not think that your database structure is useful for answering this question :)

Comment: I just added them all. Some people here also ask the database structure.

Comment: How is database structure connected to "responsive navigation bar"? Too much irrelevant information can make the question worse, not better. Just saying.

Comment: Database structure is very useful for the answer. can you provide it?

Comment: Its within the post @PraneethMadush

Comment: @AbegailGraceUlanday let me check this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. @PraneethMadush. I'll wait.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that on desktop you are relying on the :hover to reveal the dropdown. For mobile there is no hover state and so you would need to either use JavaScript (or styled form checkboxes to simulate it with html/css) that would make it a tap to reveal sub items.

This would also mean that you would not be able to click through to the top level item on dropdowns as that would expand the dropdown rather than be a link. The work around could be to make a dropdown chevron on the right that would be it's own button to reveal the sub menu on mobile and the text still link through. This is the solution I used on https://www.firetechcamp.com/

---

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without adding at least some javascript, this is the closest i could get to a pure css / html solution:

***try resizing the browser to see the responsive solution***

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
}
 
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
 
/* This hides the dropdowns */
 
 
li ul { display: none; }
 
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000000;
}
 
ul li a:hover { background: #e4e3e3; }
 
/* Display the dropdown */
 
 
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

@media( max-width: 600px ){
    
    ul li{
        float:none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease forwards;
    }

    ul li a{
        color: white;
    }
    
    ul>li:first-child{
        background: #4caf50;
        padding-right: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    ul:hover li{
        opacity: 1 !important;
        position: relative !important;
        z-index: 1 !important
    }
    
    
    ul>li:first-child:after{
      content:"☰";
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0;
      color: white;
      background: #555555;
      width: 50px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      cursor: red;
    }
    
    ul>li:not(:first-child){
        position: fixed;        
        z-index: -1;
        background: #333333;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
</ul>
```